# Passing an array as parameter from CMD to PowerShell give problems

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have problems to pass an array to PowerShell script as parameter from CMD.
Here an example of the PS code:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [string[]]$serverArray,
)

$serviceName = 'service1'

function getState {
    Process {
        $serverArray
        foreach ($server in $serverArray) {
            $servState = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $server -Filter "name='$serviceName'").State
        }
    }

getState
```

How I call script from CMD:

```
powershell -file .\script.ps1 -serverArray Server1,Server2
```

I get an error because `$serverArray` is not passed an array:

```
Server1,Server2
Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT:
0x800706BA)
At C:\script.ps1:58 char:29
+             $servState = (Get-WmiObject <<<<  Win32_Service -ComputerName $server -Filter "name='$serviceName'").State
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

If I run the same command from a PowerShell window it works because the script accepts `$serverArray` as an array:

```
.\script.ps1 -serverArray Server1,Server2
```

```
Server1
Server2
```

Comment: `-file` -> `-command`

Comment: Please make sure to test-run your [mcve] code to make sure it doesn't introduce additional errors like the spurious trailing comma in your parameter definition and the missing closing bracket of your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMD doesn't know anything about PowerShell arrays. You can pass the server list as individual tokens

```
powershell -File .\script.ps1 Server1 Server2
```

and use the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) `$args` instead of a named parameter in your script:

```
foreach ($server in $args) {
    ...
}
```

or you can [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-3.0) the value of the parameter at commas in the body:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [string]$Servers
)

$serverArray = $Servers -split ','
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run this from command prompt:
`powershell script.ps1 "Server1,Server2"`

And if you add more parameters to your script :

`powershell script.ps1 "Server1,Server2" "parameter2 argument" "parameter3 argument"`

Comment: How about `powershell -NoProfile -File .\script.ps1 ...`